# Play audio with when checkbox is checked using CSS

Tags: css, audio, checkbox, pseudo-element

Im trying to make an audio file automatically play once a checkbox is checked. My initial idea was to have the audio tag on autoplay, and configure the CSS like this:

```
audio {
    display: none;
}
[type="checkbox"]:checked~audio {
    display: inline;
}
```

This doesnt work, of course; the audio will simply play as the website is loaded. Anyone know how to accomplish this? Perhaps some way to make the same space as the checkbox' `<label>` tag be used to play the audio. Thank you.

Comment: CSS seems to be the wrong tool for this.  Are you able to use javascript?

Comment: Not really, no.

Comment: Not possible with css.

Answer (score 1):

You will likely need Javascript or something else to accomplish this.  To my knowledge there's no way to control a media player with css only.